# Поисковик загружает страницы с двумя расширениями

Tags: .htaccess, url, ссылки, robots.txt

Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники форума!

[image: поисковик грузить страницы с двумя расширениями от другого сайта с одинаковым айпи]

Недавно обнаружил что поисковики начали загружать много вот таких ссылок, т.е. с двумя расширениями `*.php` и `*.png`:

- `Домен/centr.php/hgfj/ghkgh/ghkghk/khgkg/foto1.png`
- `Домен/doc.php/hjf/hkgkg/gkhghk/foto2.png`
- `Домен/karta.php/ljhl/khgkgh/ghkg/adress.png`
- ...

Есть нормальные прямые ссылки:

- `домен/*.php`
- `домен/kartinka/foto.png`

Причем эти страницы создаются с других доменов, но с одинакового айпи-адреса, так как на одном сервере крутиться. Получается домен и конечное изображение или документ удовлетворяет требованием, но вот папки берутся из другого сайта `домен**/папка/папка/**foto1.png`.

Если перевести на айпи то страница хорошо склеивается, вида:

```
00.00.00.00/doc.php/gfhfgj/jfgjfg/jfgj/price.xlsx
```

Как правильно запретить ссылки вида: домен/*.php/**/kartinka/foto.png**?

Заранее извиняюсь, если суть своей проблемы изложил некорректно.

Comment: Хм, вот вы пример привели `Домен/centr.php/hgfj/ghkgh/ghkghk/khgkg/foto1.png`. А по адресу `Домен/hgfj/ghkgh/ghkghk/khgkg/foto1.png` есть реальная картика? Или эти части url после `.php` генерируются случайным образом?

Comment: Картинка может и была бы, только большинство ссылок на картинку имеют относительные ссылки а не абсолютные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так сделать в файле .htaccess для сервера apache

```
RewriteEngine On
# если после расширения .php идет слэш и потом может встретиться подстрока .png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php/.*\.png [NC]
# то вернем стандартую 404 ошибку сервера
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

А лучше так

```
RewriteEngine On
# если после расширения .php идет слэш, а такого не должно быть
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php/ [NC]
# то вернем стандартую 404 ошибку сервера
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, как я могу Вас отблагодарить?